# How can I convert HTML to Textile?

Tags: html, textile

I'm scraping a static html site and moving the content into a database-backed CMS.  I'd like to use Textile in the CMS.

Is there a tool out there that converts HTML into Textile, so I can scrape the existing site, convert the HTML to Textile, and insert that data into the database?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found myself trying to do this the other day and not finding anything useful, until I found [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It can convert loads of other markup formats as well - it's quite brilliant.

Comment: But you will loose styles and other things. Then you might as well convert to Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [c# lib converting html 2 textile](http://blog.zunama.com/2008/12/23/html2markup-convert-html-to-textile-in-c). Though it is textile with their additions. Not pure textile.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no javascript implementation, I wrote one: 
https://github.com/cmroanirgo/to-textile

It's a little primitive at the moment, as it's a blind port of the 'to-markdown' equivalent, but should get the job done.

Answer (score -2):

This is a simple markup replacement, nothing a good regex could not fix.

I recommend Perl, LWP::Simple and some regexes to do the whole thing (spidering, stripping design and menus, converting to textile, and then posting to the database.)

Answer (score -2):

try this simple java code hope it work for you

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Crawle
{

public static void main(String ar[])throws Exception
{


URL url = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/#q=i+am+happy");
InputStream io =  url.openStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
FileOutputStream fio = new FileOutputStream("crawler/file.txt");
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(fio,true);
String data = "";
while((data=br.readLine())!=null)
{
pr.println(data);
System.out.println(data);
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with Textile

Comment: As per the question he wants to crawler any website page and then need to save into any textfile, so what I posted in my answer is related to that only.

And In my answer I had shared the simple example for above query.

I am still not getting reason of downvote.